# ROR 5 API - Internal Server Error when doing a POST action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, api

Im trying to resolve this many days ago. I really don't know how to fix this issue. Im just a beginner with rails and im creating an api for personal use. here's my code:

users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    users = orchestrate_query(User.all)
    render serialize(users)
  end

  def show
    render serialize(user)
  end

  def create
    user = User.new(user_params)
    if user.save
      UserMailer.confirmation_email(user).deliver_now
      render serialize(user).merge(status: :created, location: user)
    else
      unprocessable_entity!(user)
    end
  end

  def update
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    if user.update(user_params)
      render serialize(user).merge(status: :ok)
    else
      unprocessable_entity!(user)
    end
  end

  def destroy
    user.destroy
    render status: :no_content
  end

  private

  def user
    @user ||= params[:id] ? User.find_by!(id: params[:id]) : User.new(user_params)
  end

  alias_method :resource, :user

  def user_params
      params.require(:data).permit(:email, :password, :given_name, :family_name, :role, :confirmation_redirect_url)
  end

end
```

users_confirmation_controller.rb:

```
class UserConfirmationsController < ActionController::API


before_action :confirmation_token_not_found

  def show
    user.confirm
    if user.confirmation_redirect_url
      redirect_to(user.confirmation_redirect_url)
    else
      render plain: 'You are now confirmed!'
    end
  end

  private

  def confirmation_token_not_found
    render(status: 404, plain: 'Token not found') unless user
  end

  def confirmation_token
    @confirmation_token ||= params[:confirmation_token]
  end

  def user
    @user ||= User.where(confirmation_token: confirmation_token).first
  end
end
```

user.rb -> model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password

  before_validation :generate_confirmation_token, on: :create
  before_validation :downcase_email

  enum role: [:user, :admin]

  validates :email, presence: true,
              uniqueness: true,
              length: { maximum: 255 },
              format: { with: /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i }

  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 8 }, if: :new_record?
  validates :given_name, length: { maximum: 100 }
  validates :family_name, length: { maximum: 100 }
  validates :confirmation_token, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: true }

  def confirm
    update_columns({
      confirmation_token: nil,
      confirmed_at: Time.now
    })
  end

  private

  def generate_confirmation_token
    self.confirmation_token = SecureRandom.hex
  end

  def downcase_email
    email.downcase! if email
  end

end
```

user_presenter.rb

```
class UserPresenter < BasePresenter
  FIELDS = [:id, :email, :given_name, :family_name, :role, :last_logged_in_at,
            :confirmed_at, :confirmation_sent_at, :reset_password_sent_at,
            :created_at, :updated_at]

  sort_by *FIELDS
  filter_by *FIELDS
  build_with *[FIELDS.push([:confirmation_token, :reset_password_token,
                           :confirmation_redirect_url,
                           :reset_password_redirect_url])].flatten

end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope :api do
    resources :resorts, except: :put
    resources :contact_info, except: :put
    resources :users, except: :put

    resources :user_confirmations, only: :show, param: :confirmation_token

    get '/search/:text', to: 'search#index'
  end

  root to: 'resorts#index'
end
```

this is my request to my REST Client;
Method: POST, URL: http://localhost:3000/api/users;
Headers: application/json; and body is:

```
{"data":{"email":"john@gmail.com",
"password": "password",
"confirmation_redirect_url":"http://google.com"}}
```

Here is the error:

```
"error": "Internal Server Error",
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:12:in `create'
```

please help me. im stuck with it for the past 3 days now.
    app/controllers/users_controller.rb:12:in `create'

Comment: any logs? Is probably the email...

Comment: What is `params.require(:data)`

Comment: what's line 12? in the users controller

Comment: line 12 is   user = User.new(user_params)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an attribute to your users table password_digest:string when using has_secure_password. I am not positive on why your errors aren't showing correctly but this should fix the problem.

## http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html

has_secure_password

**short definition**

Adds methods to set and authenticate against a BCrypt password. This mechanism requires you to have a password_digest attribute.

Comment: still i got the error:      "trace": "app/controllers/users_controller.rb:12:in `create'"

Comment: what do u mean by adding an attribute? sorry im just a beginner

Comment: rails g migration add_password_digest_to_users password_digest:string

Comment: i tried adding password_digest but it says i already have it on my create_users migration file

Answer (score -1):

Your user params require you to call the User model to access and save the attributes YOU defined in the User table

```
  def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :given_name, :family_name, :role, :confirmation_redirect_url)
  end
```

Comment: Please read the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-require) of `params.require`. Passing `:user` won't make any difference.

Comment: That doc clearly indicates that require was called on what was initialized. If you are creating a User model, how can you set the attributes on something different.

Comment: `params.require(:data)` means that the params will contain a key `data`, and `.permit` will extract the permitted attributes from it. It has nothing to do with the model.

Comment: I dont know why you would say this. I was right. I just tried it out with one of my rails app where I changed the params to a different key name from my model. Rails app did not create. Threw the same error.